# Choose between 2 algorithms in my script

Tags: python, pyqgis, algorithm

I would like to know how can user chooses between 2 algorithm's parts in my script.
User must be able to chose between 2 methods to integrate a variable : automatically with a character selection in layer name or manually with a field.
I developed both methods in 2 scripts and they works well. In each script just one part is different for this variable.
So how can I propose one or the other to user? radio button, dropdown list... And How can I do it?
Somebody has an idea?

Comment: The nicest way, in my opinion, is always a GUI. Let them select their favorite algorithm via selection of a radio button. QGIS comes with QtDesigner. It might be a good idea to watch some tutorials, but it's not that easy if you are new to GUI coding.

Comment: I'm already a beginner in script coding, so GUI coding...

Comment: You mentioned "radio buttons, dropdown lists" etc, so I thought you were amining at a GUI solution. How does the user call your script anyway?

Comment: You're right, after a little reflexion, i can't do it without a GUI. I'm searching where I can find QTDesigner in Qgis :D

Comment: For me it works if I just enter "Qt" in my start menu of windows. But I assume I checked it back when I installed all the stuff. If it's not there, download the Osgeo4w network installer: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html. And choose "advanced installation". You gain access of all plugins and tools and you can find them in the search field. But it will be a lot of work to learn how to make GUIs, add code to GUIs and make them available in QGIS. Just saying.

Comment: There isn't a GUI interface to create Gui interface? :P Maybe QtCreator do that, no ? I just find this software name...

Comment: QtDesigner is exactly that. It let's you create a GUI by placing objects directly on your window. I just say it's more difficult to handle than you think.

Comment: Oh ok ! unfortunatly, i'm working on mac... I have to find QtDesigner on it.

Comment: On mac it's very shity but possible. Otherwise if you don't want to create the UI, you could have the processing framework that create the UI for you. Have a look to this Doc https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html